# HttpClient DefaultRequestHeaders Authorization Exception

Tags: c#, http-headers, token, dotnet-httpclient

I have a class that has a private `HttpClient`.  I have a `DoRequest` method that handles all my requests and takes a template object for the content/parameters.  So far I have 2 calls.  One is to retrieve a token and one is to get some other info (GetInfo).  my `GetInfo` method will need the authorization header set so I do this before calling `DoRequest`:

```
this.Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

As soon as I started doing a `Parallel.For` for a load test, I start getting a `An item with the same key has already been added` exception, sometimes.  Now I understand that the headers are stored in a dictionary and that's why I am getting the exception but I am looking for ideas on how to solve this while retaining my `DoRequest` design.  I guess one way to solve it is to set the header in my `HttpContent` object but that lives in my `DoRequest` method and I would need to pass a Token parameter to it now.  I'm not saying that's the worst thing in the world but am looking for alternatives, if any exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I thought this problem through is by analyzing what I wanted.  I wanted to re-use `HttpClient` but dispose of any Authorization headers.  The best way I can think to do that is to use an `HttpRequestMessage` and pass the Token to my `DoRequest` method.  In my method, I do:

```
HttpRequestMessage reqmsg = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uri);
reqmsg.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token ?? string.Empty);
reqmsg.Content = formContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check and see if it's already on there:

```
static readonly object _o = new object();
...
lock (_o){
    if (!this.Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Authorization"))
        this.Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I can trust that asynchronously because it may not exist the millisecond I check and then exist right when I try to set it.

Comment: If you wrap your whole check in a lock statement, you should be thread safe.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I don't think so, that would defeat the whole point of making my calls asynchronous.  Thank you for trying to help but passing the token to my `DoRequest` method is the better solution IMO.

Comment: The lock method is making sure that a shared resource is not being accessed at the same time by multiple threads, which is what you were trying to accomplish by your first comment.  If using lock was a bad idea, then no multi threaded application could ever share resources.  FWIW, passing the token to the DoRequest is also an acceptable solution IMO :)

Comment: You are correct.  According to what I was looking for, it is A solution.  Thanks for your help Josh.

Comment: If the bulk of the work being done is after the addition of the Authorization header, the lock should have little to no performance impact as the purpose of the parallel processing is to do the work after the header on multiple threads. This is only locking the header manipulation which should take a fraction of a second.